# Is it possible to build a homepage with python on virtual server when the sudo command is disabled?

Tags: python, django

I've studied Python and Django, building a homepage.
And I've been using a virtual memory on Ubuntu server(apache2 2.4.18/ php-7.0/ MariaDB 10.0.28 with phpMyAdmin/ FTP) offered for developers.

The server hadn't allowed users to use python, but I asked the server administrator to give me a permission and I got it.
The problem was, however, that I was not allowed to use not only any sudo command line but also basic commands like `apt-get` and `python`.
The only administrator can do so, therefore it seems that I cannot install any neccessary things-virtualenv, django, and so on- by myself.

Just to check whether .py file works or not, I added `<?php include_once"test.py" ?>` on the header of index.php about the test.py where only `print "python test"`(meaning only python 2 is installed on this server) is written. It works. That is, I guess, all I can do is uploading .py file with Filezilla.

In this case, **can I make a homepage with Python on this server efficiently**? I was thinking about using Bottle Framework, but also not sure. 
I am confused with wondering whether I should use PHP on this server and using Python on PythonAnywhere in the end.

I am a beginner. Any advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: You'll need root access to access port 80

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about asking the admin to start a virtualenv for you and give you permissions to work in that environment?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I asked the admin of server and it seems he will give me permissions on a virtualenv :)